# Python Pandas ValueError: Expected object or value

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I am trying to have Python read a JSON file and export it to a CSV. I am using Pandas for the conversion, but I am getting "ValueError: Expected object or value" when I run the code below.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json ('contacts.json')
```

I am using Visual Studio Code for testing the script. When I run the above code, I get the message below in the Terminal window.

> PS C:\Users\TaRan\tableau-wdc-tutorial-part-1> & "C:/Program
> Files/Python38/python.exe" "c:/Users/TaRan/Dropbox/Team Operational
> Resources/G. BI Internal/Testing/Hubspot/conversion.py"
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "c:/Users/TaRan/Dropbox/Team Operational Resources/G. BI
> Internal/Testing/Hubspot/conversion.py", line 3, in
>
> df=pd.read_json('contacts.txt')   File "C:\Program
> Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\util_decorators.py", line
> 199, in wrapper
>
> return func(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Program
> Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\util_decorators.py", line
> 296, in wrapper
>
> return func(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Program
> Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json_json.py", line 618,
> in read_json
>
> result = json_reader.read()   File "C:\Program
> Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json_json.py", line 755,
> in read
>
> obj = self._get_object_parser(self.data)   File "C:\Program
> Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json_json.py", line 777,
> in _get_object_parser
>
> obj = FrameParser(json, **kwargs).parse()   File "C:\Program
> Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json_json.py", line 886,
> in parse
>
> self._parse_no_numpy()   File "C:\Program
> Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json_json.py", line 1119,
> in _parse_no_numpy
>
> loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None ValueError:
> Expected object or value

I thought it might be a problem with the JSON file, so I wrote a different one, but I still received the error. To me, it looks like something might be wrong with the Panadas package. I tried reinstalling it, but I still get the error.

**EDIT**

Here is a sample from the JSON file. I am displaying only one contact and changed the confidential information.

```
{"results":[{"id":"101","properties":{"createdate":"2020-06-05T15:18:37.746Z","email":"someone@aplace.com","firstname":"First","hs_object_id":"101","lastmodifieddate":"2020-08-12T15:17:35.104Z","lastname":"Last"},"createdAt":"2020-06-05T15:18:37.746Z","updatedAt":"2020-08-12T15:17:35.104Z","archived":false}],"paging":{"next":{"after":"452","link":"https://api.hubapi.com/sampleurl.com"},"prev":null}}
```

I am getting the JSON file from the Hubspot API. I am not doing any kind of formatting before pulling it into Python for the conversion (nor do I want to - I am trying to automate this entire process). Please note that my JSON is all on one line. I am not sure if this matters or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your json file is correctly formatted? I wrote this json file and it seems to work fine for me.

```
{
  "Name": {
    "0": "John",
    "1": "Nick",
    "2": "Ali",
    "3": "Joseph"
  },
  "Gender": {
    "0": "Male",
    "1": "Male",
    "2": "Female",
    "3": "Male"
  },
  "Nationality": {
    "0": "UK",
    "1": "French",
    "2": "USA",
    "3": "Brazil"
  },
  "Age": {
    "0": 10,
    "1": 25,
    "2": 35,
    "3": 29
  }
}
```

I used the same code you wrote, but added a print statement to check the output and I was able to print out the head of the dataframe.

```
% python test.py
     Name  Gender Nationality  Age
0    John    Male          UK   10
1    Nick    Male      French   25
2     Ali  Female         USA   35
3  Joseph    Male      Brazil   29
```

EDIT: Using the JSON you provided it looks like it is malformed. The JSON you provided is missing a closing "]" and also there were some missing brackets in the second array item.

It should look like this depending on what you're trying to do.

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "id": "101",
      "properties": {
        "createdate": "2020-06-05T15:18:37.746Z",
        "email": "someone@aplace.com",
        "firstname": "First",
        "hs_object_id": "101",
        "lastmodifieddate": "2020-08-12T15:17:35.104Z",
        "lastname": "Last"
      },
      "createdAt": "2020-06-05T15:18:37.746Z",
      "updatedAt": "2020-08-12T15:17:35.104Z",
      "archived": false
    },
    {
      "paging": {
        "next": {
          "after": "452",
          "link": "https://api.hubapi.com/sampleurl.com"
        },
        "prev": null
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: When I run the JSON you provided, I do not get any errors. The code I have has several parameters that isn't present what your sample code. Is it possible I'm getting the errors because of these extra bits or because it's all on one line? This is the output that I am getting from the API I am calling to.

Comment: For JSON is shouldn't matter if it is all on one line. It is possible the api you're using isn't generating properly formatted JSON.

Comment: So it appears that the JSON file that I am getting from Hubspot is incorrectly formatted. It's missing a set of {} around the last section (paging) and the ] seems to need to be moved to near the end of the code (all of this is reflected in your working code, but not mine). I wouldn't think that the output file I received from Hubspot to be incorrect, but apparently it is. Do you have any idea on how I could go about having the output file corrected from the Hubspot end (what is output)? Or, less desirably, correct the code through injecting/rearraging the correct/missing pieces via Python?

Comment: Yeah that is a tough one, I would probably try to open a ticket with Hubspot and see if they can fix their API. Trying to parse it yourself and fixing the bad formatting will be a pain.

Answer (score 1):

You have problems in your JSON format. e.g. in the posted part you have '[' but don't have ']'

Comment: That was a copy and paste error on my part. I fixed my edit in my original post.